# Small distance in list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents

how can I set a distance between section numbering in the list of tables (figures etc...).
I would like to have a small distance between 1.x and 2.x ... also 2.x and 3.x and so on...
Thank you !!

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=entryprefix]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Aktiviert EC-Schriftarten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Dateikodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         % Deutsche Einstellung
\usepackage{lmodern}                % Latin Modern
\BeforeStartingTOC[lot]{\renewcommand*\autodot{:}}  
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}                    
\renewcommand*\listoflotentryname{\bfseries\tablename}  
\counterwithin{table}{section}      


\begin{document}
    
    \listoftables \newpage
    
    \section{First Section}
    
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{Test}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{Test}
    \end{table}
    
    \section{Second Section}
    
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{Test}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{Test}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,listof=entryprefix]{scrartcl}[2020/01/24]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with older TeX distributions
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lot]{\renewcommand*\autodot{:}}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}
\renewcommand*\listoflotentryname{\bfseries\tablename}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\newcommand*{\sectionlistsgap}{10pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addsectionlistsgap}[1]{%
  \doforeachtocfile[float]{%
      \addtocontents{\@currext}{\protect\addvspace{\sectionlistsgap}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\AddtoDoHook{heading/branch/nostar/section}{\addsectionlistsgap}

\begin{document}
\listoftables \clearpage
\section{First Section}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Test}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Test}
\end{table}
\section{Second Section}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Test}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On OS windows it works great but when I try it on my macOS then i become compile errors like "Undefinied control sequence.\AddtoDoHook" . Do you know why it doesn't work with macOS?

Comment: Which KOMA-Script verison do you use on your macOS? `\AddtoDoHook` needs at least version 3.27.

Comment: where can I see it? or where can I install the new one? I use TeX Live Utility

Comment: The version used can be found in the log file. Current KOMA-Script version in TeXLive 2020 is 3.32 and the last KOMA-Script version in frozen TeXLive 2019 is 3.29.